# Executar código JavaScript no VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Não estou conseguindo executar códigos js através do VS code.

Usando a recomendação de um [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778413/run-javascript-in-visual-studio-code) instalei o [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) usando o <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> ou <kbd>F1</kbd>. Sempre tinha a seguinte mensagem :

> [Running] node "c:\Users\thiag\OneDrive\Documentos\Udemy\Desenvolvimento-Web-udemy\Seção 8 - JavaScript\163 - atividades-para-fixacao-do-conteudo\1.js"
>   'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> [Done] exited with code=1 in 0.207 seconds

Então instalei o [Quokka.js](https://quokkajs.com/). A mensagem acima se repediu e o código não foi executado.

Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Código :

```
console.log('Teste')
```

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem, mas se tu criar um arquivo html que chame ou execute esse arquivo no navegador, não te resolveria?

Comment: Sim, mas o desejo era executar direto no  vs code.

Comment: Talvez esse link te ajude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778413/run-javascript-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: Foi um dos links que deixei na pergunta. Já li esse post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amigo, pela mensagem de erro você não deve ter o nodejs instalado em sua maquina.
Javascript é uma linguagem originalmente criada para rodar no client side, mas com o nodejs você pode usar ela como um script no server-side.
Para poder executar seus arquivos .js no terminal como se fossem um script você precisa instalar o [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/).

Answer (score 0):

Como o colega disse, o pré-requisito é instalar antes o Node. Porém, **não precisa instalar nenhuma extensão adicional.** Vá no menu Run > Add Configuration, "selecionar a opção Node.js (na command pallet) e salvar o arquivo (criado), sem necessidade de configurações adicionais". Isso irá criar um arquivo launch.json para o projeto (numa subpasta oculta ".vscode"), de uso exclusivo do VS Code, evitando que ele sempre pergunte qual o environment ou interpretador que você quer usar.
Fonte: Duarte, Luiz. Programação Web com Node.js: Completo, do Front-end ao Back-end . LuizTools. Edição do Kindle - Amazon.

Para executar, teclar Ctrl + F5 ou F5. Para depurar passo-a-passo, teclar F10.

Outra alternativa bastante prática seria instalar a extensão "Node Exec" e executar apenas teclando F8.